# Not able to delete a pipeline job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and to check the functionality of Jenkins pipeline, I have created a pipeline job with some name under my main project. Now I want to delete the pipeline job but I am not able to see any delete option. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Check you permissions. Do you use any security plugins?

Comment: @FCh I am having Developer(write) access on the main project inside which this pipeline job is present. I cant check if we are using any security plugin as I don't have admin access on the Jenkins tool

Answer (score 12):

If you have delete permission you will be able to see this option :
[image: delete Pipeline]

If you don't see this then check that you are added to this job's role and that this role also has delete permission :
[image: role]

Comment: Also check browser pop is enabled